# How do I get 100 fps in Counter-Strike 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike

I am a Counter-Strike 1.6 steam user.

I am trying to get 100 fps in my system. I have checked numerous sites to increase the fps, but none of them were helpful. Please suggest me some idea. Currently i am getting 40-60 fps but ingame it drops to 20 fps.

My current system conifg is:

> System: IBM ThinkPad
>
> Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo
>
> RAM: 2.5 GB
>
> Graphics card: Intel 947 GML
>
> Monitor refresh rate: 60hz

Comment: An IBM ThinkPad would be at least 8 years old. Even though CS is fairly old itself, I expect you need an upgrade if you're looking for better performance.

Comment: You're on a laptop with a Core 2 Duo and an older Intel integrated graphics chip.  You're not going to get 100fps with that computer. The solution is to start looking for something new.

Comment: Set your resolution to **640*480**, color depth to **16 bit** and turn off all visual effects/set everything on lowest. You may get some decent *FPS* I guess. And don't forget the `fps_max ` command in your console

Comment: Thanks @TZHX i will get a new on soon but please let me share some useful settings to make the fps to atvleast 80 for current i am failing in most of the matches.BTW when my system was new it was great 100fps constant.. i was feeling like pro ... now i feel like noobest

Comment: my in game settings - 101 fps resolution and setting for resolution is 640 * 480 maxrate-25000 cl_cmdrate 101 cl_updaterate 101 ex_interp 0.01 please share me some other commands to make it great

Comment: your monitor is only going at 60hz, so anything over 60fps is wasted, unless you are trying to record in that high fps, but that dose not make sense either

Comment: can i overclock refresh rates

Comment: No, you cannot change the physical refresh rate of your monitor. Certain newer monitors run at 120Hz but this is a fixed frequency that can't be changed.

Comment: Purchasing a new system is the only solution to get rid of the problem as per you guys.I am going to suck again in todays game :(. btw thanks all :)

Comment: difference between 60 fps and 100 fps should not affect your performance, if you suck it is most likely due to other problems like latency to the server

Comment: The graphics hardware in your laptop is the bottleneck. You won't be able to update it either, so it's time to upgrade. BTW focus on increasing your minimum FPS, not your maximum FPS. 'How can I stop my framerate dropping to 20FPS' would have been a better title for this question IMHO. I assume you've reduced all your video settings, this will increase your FPS, but obviously the trade off is the quality of the graphics.

Comment: @user1402536 only bads blame the hardware.  But until you get something from this century you should do small things to milk it as much as you can.  First I say just backup your data and re-format.  Fresh Windows install can do wonders (although in your case not much will help).  If you don't wanna go that extreme, download CCleaner and make it clean EVERYTHING, defrag/optimize your HDD with JKDefrag and try turning off just about every application in your task manager not owned by SYSTEM.

Comment: In non steam i play in d3d and there is no trace of lag .But when i switch to steam there is no option of d3d.Can anyone suggest how to get d3d in steam ?

Answer (score 4):

### It won't be possible.

You've already experienced that your system *may* be capable of running Counter-Strike 1.6, but you can't reach more than 40 fps.

According to [this site](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/?snr=1_7_15__13) (btw a really cool site for gamers) and adding up the requirements for PC *and* Linux, you'll come to the conclusion of the following recommended requirements:

> Dual-core from Intel or AMD at 2.8 GHz, 1GB Memory, nVidia GeForce
>   8600/9600GT, ATI/AMD Radeaon HD2600/3600 (Graphic Drivers: nVidia 310,
>   AMD 12.11), OpenGL 2.1, 4GB Hard Drive Space, OpenAL Compatible Sound
>   Card

So let's get through this. Your CPU seems to match these requirements (I don't know your clock rate, but I think it fits). Also your RAM is enough.

Let's look at the two components that are lacking:

1. **Your graphics card.** You have an obsolete on-chip graphics card. These are known to *not to do no more than what is absolutely necessary*. They're strong enough for your OS, maybe video playback, but nothing more. As upgrading a graphics card on a notebook is quite impossible, your ThinkPad won't get more fps out of that system.
2. **Your monitor.** I don't know why you need that 100 fps mark. I think its just *"as much as possible"*, but if you really HAVE TO rely on this, your monitor only has a refresh rate of 60 Hz. That means your monitor can change his picture 60 times a second. 100 fps means 100 frames per second, so 100 different pictures. Not possible.

If you don't have to rely on exactly 100 fps, ignore my second thought. But if you only want to play stutter-free, your graphics card is the bottle neck.

Btw, if you want to record your play style and because of that you need 100 fps (maybe because you want to record at 60 fps and stutter-free), than your monitor is NOT the problem. But then your HDD writing speed and your graphics card will be.

---

While looking through the comments of your questions, I recognize you really only want fps. My answer assumes you want to play on a nice resolution, too.

Comment: Thanks @Trollwut.I was looking for 100 fps because while using hand grenade in counter strike i get  lag and fps drop too(10 - 12) and 1 year ago my machine was good (100 fps in game ) there was no trace of lag or fps drop consistent 100%.But suddenly after getting steam cs 1.6. i am experience lag and fps drop.But now after looking after your answer i think "my system was good but not is good" BTW thanks again

Comment: No problem. Just to be sure: Before you played NOT 1.6 and now you play 1.6? Because except for spamming with unnecessary programs I can't get why your system once should have been that powerful.

Comment: because my system was that much powerful 1 year  ago .so i am trying to get the details to reconfigure everything.I posted this if anyone has some tweaks to get lag free game.1year ago i was playing cs 1.6 non steam and now i purchase cs 1.6 steam and its all messed up :(

Comment: I don't think it depends on Steam. I do more think that you installed more and more useless software over all the time, that slows down the computer. Just go to "System control -> programs" and deinstall everything that you dont need anymore. :) Try also to deactivate virus scans and similar things while playing and ONLY while playing.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee you will get exactly 100 fps but these steps will surely improve your fps.

Possible reasons for low fps :-

1- Low PC Configuration

2- Internet problems

3- Background apps using too much RAM

4- Resolution Problem

5- Low priority of hl.exe

This is a full guide which explains each of them seperately,
visit this http://www.nkscslovers.co.in/2014/08/how-to-increase-fps-and-remove-lag-in.html